# How to set default value to JPA entity and liquibase

Tags: jpa, liquibase

I ha ve JPA entity, I have added one boolean property in it:

```
@Column(name = "attestation_reception_du_ok") private boolean attestationReceptionDuOk;
```

Then I ran **liquibase:diff** to generate the xml file to update my database.

Then I realized thet I needed to add a default value to my property.
So I updated the xml liquibase generated file like this :

```
<addColumn tableName="collaborateur">
         <column name="attestation_reception_du_ok" type="bit"
                 defaultValueBoolean="false"/>
</addColumn>
```

I ran liquibase, it updated the mysql table with the default value.

But then I ran liquibase again and I add this change generated :

```
<dropDefaultValue columnDataType="boolean default 0"
                        columnName="attestation_reception_du_ok"
                        tableName="collaborateur"/>
```

So I decided to update my JPA entity in order to tell liquibase to keep the default value option:

```
@Column(name = "attestation_reception_du_ok" , columnDefinition = "bit  default 0")
    private boolean attestationReceptionDuOk;
```

But even after added the default value in the JPA entity, liquibase keeps telling me to drop the default value.

How can I do in order to tell liquibase to keep the default value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue related to liquibase fixed on version 3.6. According to [this](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/90) issue tracking. Just update your liquibase version to get it to work.